# react native maps onPress marker drop problem

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

i have been trying to drop a pin on a map when i touch it, but i constantly get error:
error while updating property 'region' of a view managed by airmap null latitude

i have create constant markerPress and added it in MapView onPress, and then updated MapView.Marker

I have tried to change marker useState from null to empty object but didnt have any luck. Please help.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps';
import * as Location from "expo-location";




function HomeScreen({navigation}) {
    const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
    const [mapRegion, setMapRegion] = useState(null);
    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
    const [marker, setMarker] = useState(null)

    const markerPress = (event) => {
        setMarker({ marker: event.nativeEvent.coordinate })
    }






    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            let { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
            if (status !== "granted") {
                setErrorMsg("Permission to access location was denied");
            }

            let coordinates = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
            setLocation(location);

            setMapRegion({
                longitude: coordinates.coords.longitude,
                latitude: coordinates.coords.latitude,
                longitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                latitudeDelta: 0.0421
            });
        })();
    }, []);


    return  (
        <MapView
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            onPress={markerPress}
            style={{flex:1}}
            customMapStyle = { generatedMapStyle }
            showsUserLocation={true}
            followsUserLocation={true}
            showsMyLocationButton={true}
            initialRegion={mapRegion}>
            {
                marker &&
                <MapView.Marker coordinate={marker} />

            }
        </MapView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    map: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your `setMarker` call to this:

```
setMarker(event.nativeEvent.coordinate);
```

`event.nativeEvent.coordinate` is already a valid value for the `coordinate` prop.

---

So the correct object to pass to `coordinate` looks like this:

```
{
  latitude: ...,
  longitude: ...
}
```

and you passed this:

```
{
  marker: {
    latitude: ...,
    longitude: ...
  }  
}
```